# Как спрятать ссылку в программе при декомпиляции APK?

Tags: java, android

Ситуация следующая есть программа браузер которая открывает прописанную ссылку .
В самой программе ссылка не показывается (никто не видит от куда грузиться  страница ).

Проблема в чем при  декомпиляции APK - можно увидеть ссылку на источник (что неприемлемо)

Вот что нужно скрыть

```
            editor.putString("Url", "https://drive.google.com/.........");
            editor.apply();
```

Пробивал включать   minifyEnabled true

ничего не дало.

Comment: Это невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать обфускацию.

Вот пример одного из [обфускатора](http://jfxstore.com/stringer/docs) у которого заявлено закодирование строк, но это лишь усложнит анализ продукта, а вот на сколько, нужно проверять...

Есть похожий вопрос на [En-StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427238/hiding-strings-in-obfuscated-code), возможно он вам поможет с вашей проблемой.

Comment: А может быть вы делаете что-то "лишнее" и возможно существует иной путь решения вашей проблемы;

Comment: Если это например авторизация с приватным ключом (токен), можно реализовать веб-сервис, через который можно проводить авторизацию, при этом пользователю не будет виден, тот самый ключ, а только URL для авторизации.